# exited normally with code 137, signal 9 (SIGKILL) Log says out of memory! in R

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, shinyapps

I have an app that I have for the past year been deploying to shiny apps.io. The app has an API that retrieves three tables from AWS. The app also uploads 3 CSV files.
In the past, I used to retrieve all historical data from the database for all three years but about two weeks ago  I got the SIGKILL error. I looked at the log from shinyapp.io and I saw that it said out of memory.

I assumed that I went over the 1GB free tier on shinyapp.io. In order to reduce the size of my application, I changed my code that it would extract data from the database for only a one-month time period. This significantly reduced the amount of data that I use to import. I deployed this app to shinyapp.io and the application was working again. However, when I wanted to update the app with new data (I simply got rid of the old data and uploaded new data that was the same size)the app received the same error again and the logs said out of memory. This cant be the case since I have greatly reduced the data. I also went through my app and deleted any unnecessary code or functions.
The app itself contains the following files and folder:

csv_1 : 0.00488 KB

csv_2: 1.3 KB

csv_3: 1.3 KB

ui.R: 4.1 KB

server.R: 4.4 KB

app.R : 0.093 KB

global.R : 16.5 KB

www folder: 128 KB

config.yml : 0.535

**the tables that are imported:**

table 1: 6730 KB

table 2: 4470 KB

table 3: 2120 KB

This makes a total of 13476.23 KB which equals 0.01347623 GB. I believe if there is any other object or additional thing which gets added on behind the scenes it still should be under the 1 GB limit.

So why am I still getting this error? Is shiny apps.io just trying to get me to buy one of their plans? Are there other reasons why I could get this error? I have looked online but it seems like it only has to do with memory space on shinyapps.io

**Edit**
So I have been told that it's because my app requires 1 GB of RAM but how do I make it where my app does not require 1 GB of RAM? How can I check what is making the shiny server allocate so much RAM for my app?

Comment: It's memory (RAM) not disk space. Your app requires more than 1GB RAM but the free account only gives you 1GB RAM. If you go over the limit, you will have this error.

Comment: @lz100 yes but I have greatly simplified my app now it does not make sense that I continue to get this error. Does it mean that once I get this error I can no longer simplify my app and try to deploy it? Do I no longer have the option of using the free account although my app now is so small it most likely does not require 1 GB of RAM?

Comment: You'd better do a memory profiling of your app before deploy. A good way to test is to test an interactive app on Rstudio Cloud which also gives you 1GB RAM. If your app is fine over there but continues to have the same error on shinyapps.io, ask this in Rstudio Community.